# Wordpress: retrieve images url from post.php

Tags: wordpress, image, url

I need to retrieve images url from post.php page.
I've added a script (html2pdf) that creates a pdf from posts every time when a post is edited or created (back office only) and I have to include images' urls too... but I can't find a way to get them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: wp_get_attachment_url and similar others but if I use one of those my post.php page becomes blank. And I mean even if I try to assign to a variable that value (Eg: $testvar= wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID)) the page won't work. Moreover, $post->ID seems to be unset...

Comment: What does **print_r($post);** return?